# Bar item not show when I use segue programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uibarbuttonitem

I’m building an app which has a main vc that only existing user can log in to. The main page is the initial vc so I embed in the navigation bar to it. When I open the app in the first time I can see the bar items, but when I sign out, and log in again **I can’t see the bar items**, someone know why? Should I add some code? or maybe change some definitions?

I’m using segue programmatically like this:

```
  private var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?


   handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            if user == nil{
                
                if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") as? MainVC
                {
                    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                
            }else{
                //keep going with the code...
          })
```

In the simulator it starts with the main vc then I sign out (pic 1), then I log in (pic 2) and get back to the main vc but now I can’t see the bar items (pic 3).

[link to the app pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuyX1.png)

Comment: You are presenting MainVC twice? Don't you have an error in console?

Answer (score 0):

you must present your main vc in navigationcontroller

private var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
if user == nil{

```
            if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") as? MainVC
                  {
                      let navVc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                      
                      self.present(navVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                  }
            
        }else{
            //keep going with the code...
      })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is good now, I can see the bar items :)